# How to change one cell in a Pandas Dataframe based on multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign

I have a large dataframe that covers 70 years of GDP growth for 30 countries. The data look like this:

```
GDP    Country    Year
10     US         2000
10.2   US         2001
0      US         2002
10.2   US         2003
10.4   US         2004
10.4   US         2005
```

I have made a calculation and want to replace the `0` in the third row with a float stored in a variable called `us_2000`.

I tried using

```
df.loc[(df.Country == "US") & (df.Year == 2002), "GDP"] = us_2000
```

but  it doesn't work and I get the following warning message:

```
C:\Users\graha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3331: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
```

The data were downloaded from an API, and unfortunately that API made the index some horrendous string with the country name and a date-time. Is there a way to reassign just one value, based on its Country and Year values, without resetting the index?

Comment: It works for me without error... however to avoid this... I think it is better to use `.where` or `np.where`. Here is the syntax: `df['GDP'] = df['GDP'].where(~((df.Country == "US") & (df.Year == 2002)), us_2000)` OR `df['GDP'] = np.where((df.Country == "US") & (df.Year == 2002), us_2000, df['GDP'])`

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll give that a try.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error as above. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: then that line of code is not this issue? Prior to making a lsice on a dataframe, you should make a copy of it with `df1 = df.copy()` and then df1 = etc..

Comment: ok I'll do that thanks

Comment: Could you copy your code here? I think something is wrong in your code or in the version of your pandas. cause the same code works for me without error

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
df.loc[(df.Country == "US") & (df.Year == 2002)]["GDP"] = us_2000
```

Comment: assigning to a copy of the dataframe is not what's needed here. Look up "chained indexing"